# Keep geting logged of out ubuntu when clicking system settings in taskbar. also laggy login screen

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, login-screen, logout

Its mostly a fresh install of the latest ubuntu. I am a newb only thing i installed was pulse audio server, pulse audio volume control, and pulse mixer. It keeps setting my blue yeti microphone as the default audio device so i was trying to disable that and set default audio device to my speaker. I ended up unpluging my microphone but now i cant get into system settings. I uninstalled all pusle audio things from software mananger and this didnt fix logout issue.

Comment: Are you running Ubuntu 17.10 or 18.04? From terminal type: `lsb_release -a`

Comment: i am using Ubuntu 18.04 the login screen is super lagy. i changed nothing. i restarted multiple times before, but now i can get into system settings.